# How to get unicode value of multibyte character stored under char * in C?

Tags: c, unicode

Let's assume I don't use `<uchar.h>` from C11 and have something like this

```c
char *a = "Ā";
```

How can I get unicode value of this character (it's 256)? Doing something like this:

```c
int *a_value = (int *)a;
printf("%d\n", *a_value);
```

doesn't work.

How this character is written in memory?
gdb shows me:

```
loc a = 0x555555556004 "Ā": -60 '\304'
```

but quite don't get what does it exactly mean.

I've checked size of `a` and it's 2 bytes which is okay but doing

```c
printf("%d\n", a[0]);
printf("%d\n", a[1]);
```

also doesn't work. It gives me -60 and -128.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value is encoded as UTF-8.

`256` in binary is `100000000` (9 bits). It has more than 7 bits (but less than 12) so it need 2 bytes to be encoded in UTF-8.

The 1st byte will have the first 5 bits, the 2nd byte will have the final 6 bits.

So, again `256` in binary with 11 bits is `00100000000` or `00100` followed by `000000`

Final UTF-8 1st byte `11000100` ... `110` + `00100`
Final UTF-8 2nd byte `10000000` ... `10` + `000000`

`11000100` in decimal is `196`, or considering the MSB a sign bit: `-60`
`10000000` in decimal is `128`, or considering the MSB a sign bit: `-128`

Read more about UTF-8 encoding in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Encoding)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I see. It's worth mentioning that 110 in the first byte indicates that this character is encoded with 2 bytes and 10 in the second byte marks it as continuation of the previous one.

Answer (score 1):

Two more things:

(1) You got those weird numbers because plain characters on your machine (like many) are evidently signed.  You can see the "real" bytes by casting to `unsigned char`:

```
char *a = "Ā";
printf("%u %u\n", ((unsigned char *)a)[0], ((unsigned char *)a)[1]);
printf("%x %x\n", ((unsigned char *)a)[0], ((unsigned char *)a)[1]);
```

or by using `unsigned char` all along:

```
unsigned char *u = "Ā";
printf("%x %x\n", u[0], u[1]);
```

The `%u` version prints `196 128`, and the `%x` versions print `c4 80`.

(2) I'm not sure what you meant by "not using `<uchar.h>` from C11", but if you don't want to do the UTF-8 conversion by hand, you can convert a "multibyte string" (which is just about invariably UTF-8) to a wide or Unicode character by using the library function `mbtowc` from `<stdlib.h>`:

```
wchar_t wc;
mbtowc(&wc, a, strlen(a));
printf("%d %x\n", wc, wc);
```

This prints `256 100` on my machine, since `Ā` is U+0100.

Another useful function is `mbstowcs`, which does this for multiple characters at once:

```
char *mbs = "Daß ist sehr schön";
printf("%s\n", mbs);
wchar_t wcs[20];
int n = mbstowcs(wcs, mbs, 20);
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    printf("%3d %x %lc\n", wcs[i], wcs[i], wcs[i]);
```

When using functions like `mbtowc` and `mbstowcs`, however, you have to remember that they do *not* necessarily deal in UTF-8 and Unicode.  There are wide character encodings other than Unicode, and there are multibyte representations other than UTF-8.  In fact, to get these functions to work "correctly" on my machine I have to first call

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");
```

to tell them that it's okay to use my locale settings (namely, `en_US.UTF-8`), instead of the default "C" locale which does *not* assume Unicode.